# Parse related remote calls failing in app

Tags: parse-platform

I have developed an Ionic Framework App using Parse which works great on my desktop browsers. No errors or warnings in the browser console.

But when I package the app and test in on my actual Android 4.4.4 device, the Parse related functionalities does not work. When I tried to debug the App by installing the .apk using GapDebug tool, I see the below in the console.

```
POST https://api.parse.com/1/login net::ERR_CACHE_MISS 
POST https://api.parse.com/1/requestPasswordReset net::ERR_CACHE_MISS
```

Below is the complete console log details for the Parse Login activity.

```
POST https://api.parse.com/1/login net::ERR_CACHE_MISS parse-1.3.3.min.js:1
b._ajax parse-1.3.3.min.js:1
b._request parse-1.3.3.min.js:1
b.User.b.Object.extend.logIn parse-1.3.3.min.js:3
b.User.b.Object.extend.logIn parse-1.3.3.min.js:3
$scope.validateUser login.controller.js:22
$parseFunctionCall ionic.bundle.js:20124
(anonymous function) ionic.bundle.js:50863
Scope.$eval ionic.bundle.js:22178
Scope.$apply ionic.bundle.js:22276
(anonymous function) ionic.bundle.js:50862
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:4409
elemData.handle jquery.js:4095
triggerMouseEvent ionic.bundle.js:2811
tapClick ionic.bundle.js:2800
tapTouchEnd ionic.bundle.js:2918
POST https://api.parse.com/1/requestPasswordReset net::ERR_CACHE_MISS
```

For getting all the data for a particular class, I get the below failure object.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS  https://api.parse.com/1/Items 

XMLHttpRequest failed: {"statusText":"","status":0,"response":"","responseType":"","responseXML":null,"responseText":"","upload":{"ontimeout":null,"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null},"withCredentials":false,"readyState":4,"timeout":0,"ontimeout":null,"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null}
```

Comment: Have your find a solution ?

Comment: Yes. It was some Android permission related issue. Some how the manifest file was changed. After creating the new project with network access permission it worked.

Comment: can you share where did you change to make it work? i am facing a similar issue with my ionic app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with permission. It was failing because the app was not able to connect to internet.

Somehow the Network Access permission entry got deleted in the manifest file. After adding it to manifest, it worked.

Comment: Yes thank you, I've added this line: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` and it's fix the problem.